# Unity Build - Exception: il2cpp.exe did not run properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-ndk, il2cpp

Using Unity **2017.4.34f1 (LTS)** with **IL2CPP** with **NDK r13b**, I try to export my Unity Project to Android Project (Build Process).

Note: I'm using IL2CPP because Google PlayStore want both 32 & 64bit, so i cant use **Mono** anymore as **scripting backend**.

However, it's failed and I got below error:

```
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.34f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 arguments, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:336)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection`1 userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:317)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:160)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry, Boolean debugBuild) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:34)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:272)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

and one more error log:

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.34f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --development-mode --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp/StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.34f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.34f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="C:/android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r13b" --map-file-parser="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.34f1\Editor\Data\Tools\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\DOTween.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Facebook.Unity.Settings.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\PlayMaker.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\TextMeshPro-1.0.55.2017.1.0b12.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Analytics.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Facebook.Unity.Android.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Facebook.Unity.Canvas.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Facebook.Unity.IOS.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\mscorlib.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\Stores.dll" --assembly="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll" --generatedcppdir="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain.
    Output directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 691 of which compiled: 282
    Time Compile: 54396 milliseconds Il2CppAttributes.cpp
    Time Compile: 23198 milliseconds Bulk_TextMeshPro-1.0.55.2017.1.0b12_0.cpp
    Time Compile: 21138 milliseconds Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp
    Time Compile: 20951 milliseconds Bulk_mscorlib_16.cpp
    Time Compile: 16387 milliseconds Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.cpp
    Time Compile: 15667 milliseconds Bulk_mscorlib_17.cpp
    Time Compile: 13478 milliseconds GenericMethods24.cpp
    Time Compile: 13394 milliseconds Il2CppMetadataUsage.cpp
    Time Compile: 13278 milliseconds Bulk_Mad2D_0.cpp
    Time Compile: 12015 milliseconds Bulk_mscorlib_10.cpp
Total compilation time: 765251 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp56A5.tmp" -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_6D290C36A270BA4A86083617583BFE15\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -Xlinker -Map="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_6D290C36A270BA4A86083617583BFE15\libil2cpp.map" -rdynamic -fPIE -pie -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_init_m2214171880':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:543: undefined reference to `init'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logout_m2238411584':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:571: undefined reference to `logout'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:571: undefined reference to `logout'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_activateApp_m160690348':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:581: undefined reference to `activateApp'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:581: undefined reference to `activateApp'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logPurchase_m2329488507':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:605: undefined reference to `logPurchase'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_ui_m1731210125':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:635: undefined reference to `ui'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_m891649343':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:657: undefined reference to `initScreenPosition'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:657: undefined reference to `initScreenPosition'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(IEnumerable`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.Statistics.BuildingTestRunnerHelper.BuildAndLogStatsForTestRunner(CppProgramBuilder builder, IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++ @"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp56A5.tmp" -o "C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_6D290C36A270BA4A86083617583BFE15\libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\platforms\android-16\arch-arm" -gcc-toolchain "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "C:\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a" -lgnustl_static -llog -Xlinker -Map="C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\linkresult_6D290C36A270BA4A86083617583BFE15\libil2cpp.map" -rdynamic -fPIE -pie -fuse-ld=bfd.exe

clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_init_m2214171880':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:543: undefined reference to `init'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logout_m2238411584':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:571: undefined reference to `logout'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:571: undefined reference to `logout'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_activateApp_m160690348':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:581: undefined reference to `activateApp'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:581: undefined reference to `activateApp'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_logPurchase_m2329488507':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:605: undefined reference to `logPurchase'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_ui_m1731210125':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:635: undefined reference to `ui'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache\43B0E2C486C7D35B13D99EAC9094B83F.o: In function `CanvasJSWrapper_initScreenPosition_m891649343':
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:657: undefined reference to `initScreenPosition'
C:\Users\user\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput/Bulk_Facebook.Unity.Canvas_0.cpp:657: undefined reference to `initScreenPosition'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(IEnumerable`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.Statistics.BuildingTestRunnerHelper.BuildAndLogStatsForTestRunner(CppProgramBuilder builder, IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:336)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(ICollection`1, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:317)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:160)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:34)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

What I've Done so far:

1. Try to use **NDK r16b**, but failed because Unity 2017.4 only want **NDK r13b**
2. Run Unity as Administrator, but still not solve

==UPDATE LOG (Unity 2017.4.39):

```
Exception: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.39f1\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 arguments, System.Action`1 setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:336)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (ICollection`1 userAssemblies, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:317)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:160)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry, Boolean debugBuild) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:34)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:272)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

===UPDATE (Unity 2017.4.8f1)

Has Tried with **Unity 2017.4.8f1** (The Original where i was succesfull build APK) but still failed to export to `Android Studio Project` with x64 (IL2CPP), I'm planning to build AppBundle x64 using exported Android Native/Android Studio.

**If using internal (32bit) it was succesfull**, but Google now need **x64 APK/AppBundle** Build. If i knew this before, i would using `IL2CPP` from beginning (not internal), it's so frustating error to solve. If i'm doing migration to `Unity 2019` now, too much effort to do...

===Update (newest)

Using Unity **v2017.4.40f**, i got below error:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.  C:/Program
> Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe -classpath
> "C:\Unity2017\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar"
> org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m"
> "bundleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'C:\Users\zukijuki\project\apps\Temp\gradleOut\build.gradle'
>   line: 28
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradleOut'.
>
> > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [{name=com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-11.0.4, ext=aar}] on
> > object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.
>
> > buildToolsVersion is not specified.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 27s ] stdout[
>
> Welcome to Gradle 5.1.1!
>
> Here are the highlights of this release:
>
> - Control which dependencies can be retrieved from which repositories
> - Production-ready configuration avoidance APIs
>
> For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/release-notes.html
>
> Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster) ] exit
> code: 1 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun
> (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,
> UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
> System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run
> (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,
> UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,
> System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava
> (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1
> progress) Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
> UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir,
> System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks
> (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> ===
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> ====
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors   at
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
> (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in
> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean
> askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in
> C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Was this project originally a 2017.4.34f1 project? Or has it been updated from a different version somewhere along the line? I had this happen to me in an updated project. Making a new project on the desired version and importing the project into there solved it for me

Comment: This looks like the same question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105603/unity-2017-4-34f1-cant-build-apk-using-il2cpp

Comment: @JoshPeterson Yes, it's same question. I have tried build using old version where i was successful build with it (Unity 2017.4.8f1) but still failed.....

Comment: @Remy No, the original is 2017.4.8f1 but now it's failed, because in original my build was using internal (it was success). but now, google need x64 build, so i'm using il2cpp to build x64 but still failed

Comment: Check this this issue is solved [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944426/exception-il2cpp-exe-did-not-run-properly-unity-3d-build-issue/62155613#62155613][1]

Comment: Check this this issue is solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944426/exception-il2cpp-exe-did-not-run-properly-unity-3d-build-issue/62155613#62155613

Comment: Check this this issue is solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/62155613/10749547

Answer (score 4):

I have just ran into this issue, and believe I figured out one of the solutions to this underlying IL2CPP build issue. I have the solution in bold below to get to the point. The following is what I discovered. My issue was due to following error:

```
    stdout:
Building build.bc with EmscriptenToolChain
    Output directory: D:\xxxx\Unity\Projects\01_2d_projects\SiteEstablish\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Native
    Cache directory: D:\xxxx\Unity\Projects\01_2d_projects\SiteEstablish\Library\il2cpp_cache
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException:   File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
    ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax[image]

I had a pretty good hunch that there is no reason that should be running that file, and could only think of one area that can be coming from, the "Environment Variables". The path was located under "PATH", as "%PYTHONPATH%", which then would be the only connection to that directory with the fail. Even with those items removed from "Environment Variables", the path was still getting hit. I ended up moving the Python directory to a different location altogether, and then switched the platform from Windows back to WebGL, which then succeeded. This might have been possible without removing the directory files, but I didn't know how the behavior of Unity builds work. I tried to recreate the issue, but the builds still succeeded. So, all I can do is hope this helps.

**Semi-Solution** (please take caution in doing the following. If you remove paths from system variables, you can have a very bad day!):

In your error, you will need to find the directory paths within the "Path" system variable, and remove it. Below, you it will probably be something like "C:\Users\zukinaru\Desktop\" and can be more detailed:

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain.
    Output directory: **C:\Users\zukinaru\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a**
    Cache directory: **C:\Users\zukinaru\Desktop\orisnowyndo\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache**

Like in my image, find that "Path" variable on your system, and remove the path (save what you do so you can place them back after). Click "Ok" till it's all saved. Switch platforms from whatever back to "WebGL". I have belief that the mini applications within IL2CPP might be pulling from these system variables, and it's messing with the builds that way. I believe that's why I see this issue out there, but the errors are just slightly off, due to everyone's path variable settings all being different from pc to pc.

Comment: Hi, why related to python? i see my error log, there're no mention for python. any idea?

Comment: It's because each error will be different for each user, I'm assuming depending on the app that's running within IL2CPP. My instance breaks due my "Path" system variable pointing to a directory within Python. Others breaks depending on what's in their "Path" system variable. There seems to be multiple programs running under the surface of IL2CPP. It breaks for you with "AndroidToolChain". Mine breaks with "EmscriptenToolChain". To fix my issue, I had to remove the path to the area that was breaking to allow IL2CPP to complete it's build without breaking.

Comment: This is more of a Unity -> IL2CPP issue. It just so happens that your android paths are breaking the IL2CPP due to it using the paths for some reason.

Comment: so simply to remove path from my pc's environment variable who has mentioned in il2cpp error. is it right?

Comment: That is correct. You should be able to see in your "Path" system variable the directory path which should match close to the error's path. Keep note of which you remove, but do so, and give it a shot. If that doesn't work at first and you get the same exact error when you try to build, try to "Switch platform" between any platform, then switch the platform back to "WebGL", and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might used a Facebook plugin that is developed for newer version of Unity.
To confirm this you use an empty project + Facebook(or other plugin you'd like to test) and build it, see if the error happens.

Answer (score -3):

Change your scripting runtime to Mono instead of IL2CPP it might resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, Can mono build 64bit APK?

Comment: Yes. You can  build 64bit apk using Mono

Comment: Hi @Codemaker any idea how to do it? because i cant found any option in Unity Editor to build arm64 with Mono... thank you in advance...

Comment: my unity editor screenshot = https://prnt.sc/17an40f

Comment: another reference: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1351948/why-doesnt-mono-support-arm64.html