# Unity 2017.4.34f1 Cant build APK using IL2CPP

Tags: c#, android, c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I try to build my project using **Unity 2017.4.34f1**, because Google now need both 32 & 64 bit, so i choose **IL2CPP**.

For Android NDK, I use **r13b**

However, build failed and I get below error (**summary**) :

> Exception: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2017.4.34f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe did not run properly!

Answer (score 1):

This failure occurs because the code in the project has extern methods in C#. Methods marked as extern with a the `[Dllimport("__Internal")]` attribute must be present in a native library that is linked with the Unity player when building with the IL2CPP scripting backend.

For example, this in this project one function which causes this issue is named: `activateApp`

You have two options:

1. Build a native library with all of the methods marked as extern with the [Dllimport("__Internal")] attribute  for the target platform and architecture of the player. See this documentation for details about native plugins: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html
2. Remove the C# code which defines this extern method. You can do that with platform dependent compilation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

In this case specifically, it looks like the error comes from the Facebook SDK. See if there is a newer Facebook SDK available - I believe this may have been corrected.

Comment: Hi @JoshPeterson thanks for the answer, I have deleted facebook sdk in my project and rebuild it, but still failed, please see `update log` on my question. thank you

Comment: Hi @JoshPeterson do you have also suggestion to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071256/unity3d-build-failed-because-of-unity-error-an-asset-is-marked-with-hidefl (another different question but related to build error in Unity 2017). I prefer to migrate to Unity 2019, but effort is so huge....any idea?

Comment: The "update log" section unfortunately does not have any specific information about the error. There should be another error message after this one with more specific information though.

Comment: I'm unsure about the other error message, but there are some answers on that question that might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, any idea to find `[Dllimport("__Internal")]` attributes in code? thank you.

Comment: You can search the source code. For pre-built assemblies use a reflection tool like ILSpy to search them.