# Unity3D - Build Failed because of "[Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:"

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, game-engine

Using **Unity Cloud Build Service**, i my build failed because of ***"[Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:"*** error.

What I've done so far:

1) i have tried to delete `Project Setting` and reopen Unity but build is still failed...

2) Change all "Arial" font to custom font on prefab and on all scene, but still failed...

Below are compact log of Unity Build Service:

```
1207: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1208: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default shader.
1209: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1210: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
1211: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1212: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1213: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1214: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1215: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1216: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1217: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default shader.
1218: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1219: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
1220: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Memorize_Alphabet_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1221: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Memorize_Alphabet_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1222: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Memorize_Alphabet_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1223: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Memorize_Alphabet_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1224: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Memorize_Alphabet_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1225: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1226: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default shader.
1227: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1228: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
1229: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'VR/SpatialMapping/Wireframe' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1230: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'VR/SpatialMapping/Wireframe' - Setting to default shader.
1231: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VR/BlitTexArraySliceToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1232: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/VR/BlitTexArraySliceToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
1233: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'AR/TangoARRender' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1234: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'AR/TangoARRender' - Setting to default shader.
1235: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1236: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1237: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1238: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1239: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1240: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1241: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1242: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1243: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1244: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1245: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1246: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1247: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1248: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1249: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1250: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1251: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1252: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1253: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1254: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1255: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1256: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1257: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1258: [Unity] Asset name: Lucida Grande Warning
1259: [Unity] Asset name: Lucida Grande Warning
1260: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:
1261: [Unity] ERROR: Building - Failed to write file: 0000000000000000d000000000000000
1262: [Unity] ERROR: File Library/Unused/20ae6e83037504fb99d7208afe1c36b4 couldn't be written. Because moving /BUILD_PATH/.dwwuslmlg/Temp/UnityTempFile-86ecb9516b1844531adb4c072554c356 to /BUILD_PATH/Library/Preferences/Unity/Editor-5.x/Layouts/LastLayout.dwlt failed.
1263: [Unity] ERROR: File Library/Unused/20ae6e83037504fb99d7208afe1c36b4 couldn't be written. Because moving /BUILD_PATH/pt.dwwuslmlg/Temp/UnityTempFile-b24e1fe5446324486b458ff5fe9e8e9d to /BUILD_PATH/Library/Preferences/Unity/Editor-5.x/Layouts/LastLayout.dwlt failed.
1264: publishing finished successfully.
1265: Finished: FAILURE
```

For Full Log You can Find [here...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e45lhz2hvy0206z/unity_build_full_error_log.txt?dl=0)

Any Idea ?

Thank You In Advance...

Answer (score 2):

i will break your log to parts and answer you

```
1207: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Pass '' has no 
vertex shader
1208: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth' - Setting to default 
 shader.
1209: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
1210: [Unity] WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/BlitToDepth_MSAA' - Setting to default shader.
```

in here there are some shader errors (i think those are post processing shaders)
check these shaders `BlitToDepth_MSAA` `BlitToDepth`

```
1211: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1212: [Unity] Script attached to 'Scene Variables' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1213: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1214: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
1215: [Unity] Script attached to 'Missing Prefab (Dummy)' in scene 'Assets/z_scene/ENGLISH/Games/EN_Guess_Object_Portable.unity' is missing or no valid script is attached.
```

those error are from some objects and scenes 
go to `EN_Guess_Object_Portable` scene and check the `scene variables` object. this object have invalid scripts.

and there is prefab that is missing and that prefab has invalid scripts too. check `Missing Prefab (Dummy)` object in the same scene

`1235: [Unity] ERROR: An asset is marked with HideFlags.DontSave but is included in the build:`

to solve this error you need to untick all the scenes from your build settings

then you need to build one scene at time by ticking one scene and and clicking build
that way you can find what scene have the error then you can solve the error in that scene

and look at asset call `Lucida Grande` this asset have some errors

Comment: Thank You, I wil try

Comment: Hi @Yonal I have check all of my font, there're no "Lucida Grande", also i have deleted all missing prefab. but build still failed and error message still same. any idea ?

Comment: also i have untick all scene and create blank scene to build setting, but build error is still same...

Comment: @coderInrRain are you using editor scripts (ones that have "using UnityEditor" in them)
then place those script files in a folder named "Editor" then try to build

Comment: @Yohnal what's alembic ?

Comment: @coderInrRain alambic is animation thing google it and you will find it

Comment: yes, there's animation but i'm not sure about it. and editor scripts, no...

Comment: @coderInrRain alambic is not animation. what alambic does is it bakes animations so that you can stream animations directly from unity

Comment: Hi @Yohnal, any idea about UnityEditor Scripts? How to check if i'm using it?

Comment: @Yohnal Bounty reopened...please update the answer if you want...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is caused by the **DoozyUI** plugin, there is a similar case on [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-builds-failing-an-asset-is-marked-with-hideflags-dontsave.720038/) unity forum.

> We have had other customers experience the exact same behaviour with the DoozyUI plugin. The problem was with GUISkins within the plugin, once moved to the Editor Default Resources folder and related scripts fixed, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Hi 0xBFE1A8 yes i have doozy ui plugin, i will check for this... thank you

Comment: I have remove Doozy UI plugin, but still cant solve, build error still appear...

Comment: I have tried it, but migrating to Unity 2019 will make too much effort for now.